# How can I populate a 2d array with the integers from 2 1d arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 1d arrays that need to do some math and populate 1 2d array with the answers.

```
private static void Trajectory(double[] row, double [] col) 
{
    trajectory = new int[numSpeeds][numAngles];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds; i++);
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numAngles; j++);
        {
            trajectory [i][j] = (int) ((row[i] * col[j]) / 9.8);
        }           
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(trajectory));
}
```

When I run this code, I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
at CatapultRunner.Trajectory(CatapultRunner.java:126)
at CatapultRunner.readingFile(CatapultRunner.java:100)
at CatapultRunner.main(CatapultRunner.java:38)
```

But when I I call for an index of one array and and index of the other array and tell it where to put it in the 2d array, it does exactly what I want it to do.

Example:

```
private static void Trajectory(double[] row, double [] col) 
{
    trajectory = new int[numSpeeds][numAngles];
    int i = 0, j = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds; i++);
    {
        for (j = 0; j < numAngles; j++);
        {
            trajectory [0][0] = (int) ((row[0] * col[0]) / 9.8);
        }           
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(trajectory));
}
```

Output:

```
[[10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

What am I missing for this 2d array to populate through the embedded loop?

Comment: what are numSpeeds and numAngles ? Better use row.length and col.length for the loop and for creating the new [][] array

Comment: give as the code where you are calling this method.

Comment: I am calling it with:  Trajectory(speed, angle);

Comment: At the top of your method, add a `System.out.println()` call that displays numSpeeds, row.length, numAngles and col.length. If the numbers aren't what you expect, there's your problem.

Comment: I added:  
    System.out.println("\nNumber of speeds " + numSpeeds);
    System.out.println("\nNumber of angles " + numAngles);

output:
     
     Number of speeds 6

     Number of angles 2
 
     [[126, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]

Comment: add to start of method `if (row.length < numSpeeds) throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enough speeds"); if (col.length < numAngles) throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enough angles");`

Comment: I still get the same thing. Output is the same.

Comment: remove the semi-colon after the loop lines: `for (...) ;` and use/configure the IDE to warn about empty statements; also better declare the loop variable inside the statement: `for (int i = 0; ...)`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger It was those semi-colon's. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer, there is a semicolon `;` after each loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds; i++) ;
```

this is a loop over an empty statement, just increasing `i`. Change it to

```
for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds; i++)
```

Also advised to declare the variable inside the `for` like in

```
for (int i = 0; i < numSpeeds; i++)
```

this would result in an error if the semicolon was there.

**Edit**: please also consider [the points suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54621175/85421) by @user2004685 and @Jason - makes the code more *robust* and re-usable!

Answer (score 1):

> When I run this code, I get an error:
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   16

This is probably because either the length of your **row** array is less than **numSpeeds** or the length of your **col** array is less than **numAngles**.

You shall initialize your **trajectory** array as follows,

```
trajectory = new int[row.length][col.length];

                         ^            ^
                    * Notice the changes here.
```

**EDIT:** As @Jason pointed out correctly, you'll have to remove those semi-colons from the end of your **for** statements.

```
for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds - 1; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < numAngles - 1; j++) {
        trajectory [i][j] = (int) ((row[i] * col[j]) / 9.8);
    }           
}
```

Comment: I have tried that. I get the same output either way.

Comment: You'd need to fix the for loop terminating statements as well (to remove the references to numSpeeds and numAngles.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for pointing this out. I totally missed it. I have edited my answer to highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess based on what I am able to discern from the code shown above would be that either: row.length < numSpeeds or col.length < numAngles
I would check these properties to ensure that you are not trying to access an element which is greater than the size of either of these arrays.
For example, if you have the following situation:

```
double array = {0.0}; 
int numSpeeds = 1; 
int trajectory = array[numSpeeds];
```

Would cause an error because there is no element at position 1 within 'array' (as arrays begin indexing at 0). It might be an off by 1 error in which case I suggest modifying the forloops condition to account for this error. E.g. Change the existing code into:

```
private static void Trajectory(double[] row, double [] col) 
{
trajectory = new int[numSpeeds][numAngles];
int i = 0, j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < numSpeeds - 1; i++);
{
    for (j = 0; j < numAngles - 1; j++);
    {
        trajectory [i][j] = (int) ((row[i] * col[j]) / 9.8);
    }           
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(trajectory));
}
```

Which may solve your issue. Please note that this is not a conclusive answer to the issue, as it all depends on the length of both row and col, and whether they are exceeded by numSpeeds and numAngles respectively.

Comment: `row` and  `col` are not the best names, maybe `row` is the one with the (19) angles and `col` only got the 16 speeds?!